# Why I failed the throwing-error test when testing via mochai and chai?

Tags: javascript, testing, error-handling, ecmascript-6, chai

I want to test whether a function could throw an error when facing some cases, but it always failed the test(the 1st one), but when I wrote a single simple test (the 2nd one), it passed, why?

**function to test**

```
export function add(numbers){
    let nums = numbers.split(",")
    let temp = 0
    for (let num of nums) {
        num = parseInt(num)
        if (num < 0) {
            throw new Error("negative not allowed")
        }
        temp += num
    }
    return temp;
}
```

**this is the test**

```
import chai from "chai"
import {add} from "../try"

let expect = chai.expect
let should = chai.should()

describe("about the error throwing case", function(){
    it("should throw an error when get a negative number", function(){
        expect(add("-1,2,3")).to.throw("negative not allowed")
    })

    it("should pass the throw-error test", function(){
        (function(){throw new Error("i am an error")}).should.throw("i am an error")
        expect(function(){throw new Error("i am an error")}).to.throw("i am an error")    
    })
})
```

**results**

```
./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha test/testtry.js --require babel-register -u tdd --reporter spec



  about the error throwing case
    1) should throw an error when get a negative number
    ✓ should pass the throw-error test


  1 passing (18ms)
  1 failing

  1) about the error throwing case should throw an error when get a negative number:
     Error: negative not allowed
      at add (try.js:7:19)
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/testtry.js:9:16)
```

Why and how to solve it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass a function to `expect()`, not a function call:

```
expect(function() {add("-1,2,3")}).to.throw("negative not allowed")
```